# Programmatically get keyboard frame in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a `UITableView` where I want to show the keyboard. This is hiding my last row and therefore I would like to get the keyboard frame and then calculate the size of the cell.

How can I get the frame of the keyboard programmatically in Swift?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to listen to `UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` notifications in your view controller:

```swift
let observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
    let frame = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    // do something with the frame
}
```

And don't forget to remove the observer later so that it doesn't cause any memory issues (such as strong reference cycles or even crashes):

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
```

Comment: you should remove the observer once the view controller is dismissed.

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 2.0, use the following to add an observer in `viewDidLoad()`

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
    selector: "keyboardWillShow:",
    name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
    object: nil
)
```

The second method still works in Swift 2.0